# List comprehension on a list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries like so:

```
[{'end': 34,
  'entity_group': 'ORG',
  'score': 0.99919325,
  'start': 0,
  'word': ' Community College Alabama'},
 {'end': 54,
  'entity_group': 'LOC',
  'score': 0.90115756,
  'start': 42,
  'word': ' Maxwell Blvd'},
 {'end': 66,
  'entity_group': 'LOC',
  'score': 0.9890175,
  'start': 56,
  'word': ' Montgomery'},
 {'end': 70,
  'entity_group': 'LOC',
  'score': 0.9988833,
  'start': 68,
  'word': ' AL'}]
```

I would like to extract values of `word`, but only the ones where `'entity_group': 'LOC'`. So for the above example, that would be:

```py
[' Maxwell Blvd', ' Montgomery', ' AL']
```

I have tried to do this:

```py
[[item for item in d.items()] for d in a]
```

... but this does not yield what I want.

Comment: `[ inner_dict.get('word') for inner_dict in data if inner_dict.get('entity_group')=='LOC']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
[d['word'] for d in a if d['entity_group'] == 'LOC']
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with `get` just to be safe in case the `entity_group` key is not present in your dict. If you use brackets to access that non-existing key you'll get a `KeyError`.

```py
  data = [{'end': 34,
  'entity_group': 'ORG',
  'score': 0.99919325,
  'start': 0,
  'word': ' Community College Alabama'},
 {'end': 54,
  'entity_group': 'LOC',
  'score': 0.90115756,
  'start': 42,
  'word': ' Maxwell Blvd'},
 {'end': 66,
  'entity_group': 'LOC',
  'score': 0.9890175,
  'start': 56,
  'word': ' Montgomery'},
 {'end': 70,
  'entity_group': 'LOC',
  'score': 0.9988833,
  'start': 68,
  'word': ' AL'}]

  words_for_loc_group = [item.get('word') for item in data if item.get('entity_group') == 'LOC']
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this works for you.

```py
data = [
    {'entity_group': 'ORG', 'score': 0.99919325, 'word': ' Community College Alabama', 'start': 0, 'end': 34}, 
    {'entity_group': 'LOC', 'score': 0.90115756, 'word': ' Maxwell Blvd', 'start': 42, 'end': 54}, 
    {'entity_group': 'LOC', 'score': 0.9890175, 'word': ' Montgomery', 'start': 56, 'end': 66}, 
    {'entity_group': 'LOC', 'score': 0.9988833, 'word': ' AL', 'start': 68, 'end': 70}]



res = [i.get("word") for i in data if i.get("entity_group") == "LOC"]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).